# How to get the xpath for the span button

Tags: selenium, ide

I am new to selenium IDE and trying to get the target in the right order.
I have tried many combination to get the right element when there is span for the button. I need to get the xpath for the "Read More" button.Can someone please advise how the target in the IDE should be.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="is_centered l_bottom_pad">
<a class="btn_teal_outline has_arrow" href="https://test.com/jobs/view.php?id=8">
<span>Read More</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show a few of the things you've tried?

Answer (score 4):

In some browsers (I think it was mainly MSIE) it is necessary to address the `<a>` element, not its child `<span>` in order to click a button or link. So you should adress:

```
//a[span[text()='Read More']]
```

Or you go directly for LinkText ("Read More") instead of XPath!

Comment: Although you're obviously using Selenium IDE, which is only available in Firefox anyway, right? But I think it's cleaner anyway to address the `<a>` instead of the `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

> Targeting for span button is very simple. Just see what is unique attribute in that element.
>   I feel the button text itself is unique.Try this one

```
xpath=.//span[text()='Read More']
```