# How to find the xpath for the Apply button in many div's

Tags: selenium, xpath, ide

I am new to selenium IDE and trying to get the target in the right order. I have tried many combination to get the right element when there are few div's in the page. I have copy the full xpate as well but it somehow didn't work as well. I need to get the xpath for the "Apply job" button.Can someone please advise how the target in the IDE should be. Here is the code. Thanks.

```
<div id="job-viewport">
<div class="positionDescription">
<div class="mceWrapper">
<div class="columnOneFooter">
<div>
<a class="btn btnAction apply noCaps" style="background-color: transparent;">Apply Job</a>
<div id="foot-link">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you have a look at the answers in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35796732/2932244). Both the questions are pretty much the same. I'm sure you'll be able to apply the same logic here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome:

go to you page

right click -> inspect

find your element in the sidebar, right click -> COPY -> xpath

Answer (score 0):

//a[contains(text(),'Apply Job')]

Answer (score 0):

You can use
1. `By.LinkText("Apply Job")`
2. `By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'Apply Job')]")`
3. `By.XPath("//*[@id='job-viewport']//a")`